# How to remove blank paragraphs of a document converted in string?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a very large string, which I get using this GAS methods: `var myDocText = DocumentApp.openById(docId).getBody().copy().getText();` (the `getText()` method "Retrieves the contents of the element as a text string.")

And I want to remove the caracters corresponding to the blank paragraphs and new lines of that document converted in a string. How can I do that?

I'm using this GAS body method (which reduces, but doesn't delete all blank lines):

```
  var myText = DocumentApp.openById(docId).getBody();
  for (var c = 0; c < myText.getNumChildren(); c++){
    var child = myText.getChild(c);
    if ( (child.getType() == DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH) && ( (child.getText() == '') || (child.getText() == ' ') ) ) {
      myText.removeChild(child);
      }
  }
```

But I'd like to use a string solution. I've tried `.replace(/^\s*[\r\n]/gm)`; and it didn't work`. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I would do

```
myText.split(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm).join('');
```